# Collation at server level is causing issues with case sensitivity in database procedures

Tags: sql-server, collation

I am in the process of installing a database onto a client's server. The collation that is set on the server is SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS, so it is case-sensitive.

The database that I am installing uses collation level SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS, so it is case-insensitive.

The issue I am running into now is that all variables in stored procedures must be case sensitive or else it will throw an error.

Example:

```
Declare @Dimension varchar(45)
Set @dimension = 'Test'
```

Error:

```
Must declare the scalar variable "@dimension".
```

The lowercase "d" in the @dimension variable is causing it to be recognized as a completely different variable.

Is there a setting in the database that I can update to ignore the Server's collation?

Note: I received permission to update the collation at the server level as it is a test server. However, it is a more involved process. I am looking for a way to get around this without having to go through the steps found in this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/collations/set-or-change-the-server-collation):

- Make sure you have all the information or scripts needed to re-create your user databases and all the objects in them.
- Export all your data using a tool such as the bcp Utility. For more information, see Bulk Import and Export of Data (SQL Server).
- Drop all the user databases.
- Rebuild the master database specifying the new collation in the SQLCOLLATION property of the setup command. For example:
- `Setup /QUIET /ACTION=REBUILDDATABASE /INSTANCENAME=InstanceName

  /SQLSYSADMINACCOUNTS=accounts /[ SAPWD= StrongPassword ]

  /SQLCOLLATION=CollationName`
- Create all the databases and all the objects in them.
- Import all your data.

Thank you

Comment: i think the faster way would be backup all databases then reinstall the sql-server with the correct collation then restore all databases. might be a manual thing for permissions. but there can be other options

Comment: Is the production server case sensitive? If so, changing the collation of the test server is very bad idea. The time to find collation issues is not during deployment.

Comment: @maSTAShuFu this is the approach we are looking to take now. If you write this as an answer I will mark it as correct. Thank you

Comment: @SeanLange This is certainly something I will look into as this could be a much larger problem. Thank you for the idea

Comment: Also keep in mind that since the server is currently case sensitive you may have other issues when changing the collation. Errors like duplicate variables being defined because CustomerID and customerID are not the same thing in a CS collation, but are the same in a CI collation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per experience would be a faster way is to backup all databases then re-install the sql-server with the correct collation, then restore all databases. Might be a manual thing for permissions but there can be other options.

Answer (score 5):

To work around this, set your database as [Partially Contained](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/contained-databases).  This will give you [Contained Database Collation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/contained-database-collations), which provides:

> Since a design objective of contained databases is to make them
>   self-contained, the dependence on the instance and tempdb collations
>   must be severed. To do this, contained databases introduce the concept
>   of the catalog collation. The catalog collation is used for system
>   metadata and transient objects.
>
> In a contained database, the catalog collation
>   Latin1_General_100_CI_AS_WS_KS_SC. This collation is the same for all
>   contained databases on all instances of SQL Server and cannot be
>   changed.

Comment: This is a good approach that we can take when we move to the production server if the collation is case-sensitive